# Standardize This Code According To Bootstrap v3.3.2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The code works as I want it to. I just want to know if bootstrap allows me to do this without adding my own class `center-align` ? Or if there are any disadvantages to adding this class?

HTML:-

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 center-align">
            <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 center-align">
            <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 center-align">
            <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 center-align">
            <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

CSS:-

```
.center-align {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 390px;
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
}
```

jsfiddle:- http://jsfiddle.net/dzscuam0/2/

Comment: do you mean something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/stoh6Lme/

Comment: The `center-align` class is a little weird, because it's using `width=100%` and `max-width:390px` at the same time that `col-xs-4` is being used.  I think `col-xs-4` should be enough, in a lot of cases, to regulate the width. @melc's approach is slightly more on target. Also this is sort of a code review question, not really an SO question.

Comment: @melc `max-width: 390px;` This part is missed. The width doesn't increases more than 390px in the original jsfiddle.

Comment: `Also this is sort of a code review question, not really an SO question.` Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting a class on each element, i would probably wrap the block that needs to get centered and apply `.center-block` to that (as mentioned here https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/11771).

The `.center-block` helper class will provide the `margin:auto` part of the style. Then for the width i would probably go with something relative or specify the exact width as you've done.

**html**

```
 <div class="container">
<!-- style has been applied inline to simplify the example -->
        <div class="center-block" style="width:80%;text-align:center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="col-xs-3">1</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">2</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">3</div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->
```

example
http://jsfiddle.net/zLzuw62v/

Comment: `max-width: 390px;` This part is missed. The width doesn't increases more than 390px in the original jsfiddle.

Comment: ok, I can actually adjust that `80%` according to my needs. So, your answer is helpful to me. Actually, there is a tie, from my side, between your answer and David's answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap has a class that will do half of exactly what you want, called

.center-block

The only problem with this class is that it doesn't contain

```
float: none;
```

Add that and it works just fine.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzscuam0/3/)